# ElasticSearch query with filter or bool

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 fields, for example, `field1`, `field2` and `field3`.
I need to create something like this:

`if {
    field1 != 1 AND field2 != 1 AND field3 != 1
} OR if {
    field1 != 2 AND field2 != 2 AND field3 != 2
}`

I tried to do it via two `bool` `query`, but it returns me nothing.
Then I tried to wrap these queries into one `filter`, but it always throws me exception `no query defined for [filter]]`. But my `bool` `query` for this filter is always empty and it returns me nothing. Can I add something to this `bool` `query` to retrieve all results and then filter them? Or I need to create query in another way, but how?

Comment: What version of ES are you running?

Comment: @Val ES version 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "and": [
              {
                "not": {
                  "term": {
                    "field1": "1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "not": {
                  "term": {
                    "field2": "1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "not": {
                  "term": {
                    "field3": "1"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "and": [
              {
                "not": {
                  "term": {
                    "field1": "2"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "not": {
                  "term": {
                    "field2": "2"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "not": {
                  "term": {
                    "field3": "2"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not work for me. It doesn't find anything. Maybe it is because I use 1.5.2 ES?

Comment: @Squeez Can you share your index mapping and also the actual values you're trying to negate on? (I'm guessing it's not 1 and 2).